# Can't read txt file with Scanner in Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I'm having difficulty reading a **.txt** file (words.txt) for a project I'm working on within **Eclipse** (jre1.8.0_181). I have a copy of words.txt in

```
String wordsPath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\words.txt";
```

as well as in the project directory itself (which I tried to define multiple ways):

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String wordsPath2 = workingDir.concat("\\words.txt");
String wordsPath3 = new File("").getAbsolutePath().concat("\\words.txt");
```

However, when I attempt to establish `filein`:

```
Scanner filein = new Scanner(new File(wordsPath));
filein = new Scanner(new File(wordsPath2));
filein = new Scanner(new File(wordsPath3));
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException` on all attempts. Does anybody have any insight into this? I know the files are there; what else am I missing? I have the right imports as well, I believe (`import java.io.File;` and `import java.util.Scanner;`). I looked through as many similar questions I could find, no luck. Many thanks!

Comment: What exactly does the FileNotFoundException say?

Comment: You have test that the program has permission to access the files?

Comment: Please provide the output of `System.out.println(wordsPath2)`, and the exact line at which you are getting the exception. I suspect it could be missing `\\Documents` in `wordsPath2`, e.g. `String wordsPath2 = workingDir.concat("\\Documents\\words.txt");`

Comment: Did you try refreshing (right click -> refresh) the project folder after copying the file in there? That will SYNC your file system with Eclipse's internal file system.

Comment: So apparently the compiler required a try/catch block for it, and I couldn't even try running it since I wasn't catching it. I had no idea that it was that stringent, but I apologize for not trying that sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both files in below program can be read without any error. Compare and see whether you are doing something wrong.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
      System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
      System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

      Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\prasad.karunagoda\\words2.txt"));
      System.out.println(scanner2.nextLine());
      System.out.println(scanner2.nextLine());
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It ended up being the try/catch statement. The compiler required it for some reason. Thank you.